# Collect rows to columns in Scala Spark using partitionBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, window-functions, partitioning

I have a question. Suppose I have such data:

```
name | surname | info | groupId
-------------------------------
John | Silver  | 123  | 1 
-------------------------------
Mary | Silver  | 144  | 2
------------------------------
Qwer | Tyyyyy  | 255  | 1
```

I want to get it like this:

```
name | surname | info | name-2  | surname-2 | info-2 | groupId 
------------------------------- |-------------------------------------
John | Silver  | 123  | Qwer    | Tyyyyy    | 255    | 1
------------------------------- |-------------------------------------
Mary | Silver  | 144  | null    | null      | null   | 2
```

I think it is something with `Window.partitionBy("groupId")` and then I want to put all rows in partition as columns. Help pls

Answer (score 0):

This can be a working solution for you
use **`first()`** with **`groupBy()`** along with **`row_number()`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("john","silver",123,1),("Mary","Silver",144,2),("Qwer","Tyyy",255,1)],["name","surname","info","groupId"])
df.show()
_w = W.partitionBy("groupId").orderBy(F.col("info").desc())


df = df.withColumn("rnk", F.row_number().over(_w))
df_grp = df.groupBy("groupId").pivot("rnk").agg(F.first("surname").alias("surname"), F.first("info").alias("info"),F.first("name").alias("name"))
display(df_grp)

+----+-------+----+-------+
|name|surname|info|groupId|
+----+-------+----+-------+
|john| silver| 123|      1|
|Mary| Silver| 144|      2|
|Qwer|   Tyyy| 255|      1|
+----+-------+----+-------+

   +-------+---------+------+------+---------+------+------+
|groupId|1_surname|1_info|1_name|2_surname|2_info|2_name|
+-------+---------+------+------+---------+------+------+
|      1|     Tyyy|   255|  Qwer|   silver|   123|  john|
|      2|   Silver|   144|  Mary|     null|  null|  null|
+-------+---------+------+------+---------+------+------+
```

Comment: Sorry, I have to mention that there can be more than two rows after partitionBy so it looks like "first" and "last" won't do the thing:(

And your solution copies row if there is only one after partition. I want there to be nulls or some default value.

Comment: Or is there a way to do it if know that there must be no more than 5 rows?

Comment: okay.. I have updated my answer - pls let me know if that helps to you - appreciate if you can accept and upvote